# Calculating the Local Lunar Sky at a specific point in lunar coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, astronomy, celestial-mechanics, moon, telescopes

How can one calculate the local sky observable from any given point on the Moon, expressed in lunar coordinates? Specifically, I would like to understand the methodology and equations involved in determining the positions of celestial objects such as stars, planets, and the Earth, as viewed from a specific lunar location. Are there any established algorithms or tools available for this purpose? Additionally, are there any factors unique to the lunar environment that need to be considered when performing such calculations?